# Is my Java project/library created from "scratch" if I use JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

By "scratch" I mean implemented without external libraries, only the Java SE Development Kit 8.  Obviously I am "using" *a* library(JUnit), but the logic of my program is not.

Comment: Each app is built from scratch. Using a third party library just means that you avoid reinventig the wheel and spending time in making something that someone has already implemented and tested.

Comment: @BackSlash Hm.  What term would you use to describe an app like mine?

Comment: According to the definition of whom? Is there a third party that will be evaluating this project/library? If so, it is their input you seek. Best of luck!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I would like to describe it that way.  What word would you use?

Comment: @defoification I would define it "a java app". Focus on describing what it does and which benefits it has, I don't think anyone here really cares about which third party libraries an app uses. If it works and does the job efficiently it's a good app. This is everything people wants to know.

Comment: @defoifocation: Why are you trying to avoid having external dependencies? If it has some sort of benefit, then you should probably describe it in terms of that benefit.

Comment: @ruakh To gain experience mostly.  But also to make the app look more "impressive."  Do you think I am wasting my time?  I add everything I implement to a library

Comment: @defoification: I don't think that avoiding dependencies will give you more experience; just *different* experience. Your time is a finite resource, so instead of spending effort on distinguishing functionality that makes your program awesome and worthwhile, you'll be spending that same effort on non-distinguishing functionality that you could have gotten for free from a library. (And I definitely wouldn't consider that "impressive".)

Comment: @defoification: (Note: that's not to say that it never makes sense to reproduce *some* functionality that you could also have gotten from a library. I actually do that fairly often (in non-work projects); you can gain a deeper understanding that way. But since your time is finite, you should only do that with specific things where you think it'll be worthwhile, not with *everything*.)

Comment: @ruakh thanks a lot.  This makes sense.  Great insight

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JUnit only as a dependency for your test code you are fine. You can compile and deploy a `.jar` of your productive code without the need for a dependency to JUnit because test code should not be a part of the productive code and can be excluded when compiling the productive bundle.